# joining/merging both index and non-index columns in a pandas multi-index

Tags: pandas, join, indexing, merge, dask

**Context:**
I have two very large pandas dataframes to join which barely fit in memory (8GB each, millions of rows) and have the challenge of performing a performant join using combinations of both indexed and non-indexed columns. Fuzzy joining is out of scope.

**Variables in order of cardinality:**

dataset_1 has these variables: 
*postcode, street_name, secondary_number, primary_number, unique_id*

dataset_2 has these variables:
*postcode, street_name, house_number, house_name, sub_building_name, different_unique_id*

*postcode* and *street_name* are shared keys, and multiindexing seems the correct choice to improve joining performance in pandas:

```
dataset_1 = dataset_1.set_index(['postcode', 'street', "unique_id"]).sort_index()
dataset_2 = dataset_2.set_index(['postcode', 'street', "different_unique_id"]).sort_index()
```

**Processing:**

At this stage I can compute in pandas if memory allows. If not, I would use Dask, however it can't handle multi-indexes. In the event this were possible (or unnecessary) the sorting would still need to be handled in pandas as Dask cannot manage this. If Dask were an option this is how I would convert:

```
dd1 = dd.from_pandas(dataset_1, npartitions=1) #large left dataframe
del dataset_1 #to release the memory

dd2 = dd.from_pandas(dataset_2, npartitions=3) #partitioned right dataframe for performance
del dataset_2 #to release the memory
```

**Problem:**
The challenge is performing an inner join on non-null variables using the indexes ("*postcode*" and "*street*"), alongside non-indexed columns. Combinations of the non-indexed variables will be iterated in a for loop.

**Solution Sketch:**
This gives an idea what I would like to do to maintain the performance gains from the indexing, but is of course not syntactically possible:

```
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=["postcode", "street_name", "secondary_number", "primary_number"], right_on=["postcode", "street_name", "house_name", "house_number"], left_index=[True,True,False,False], right_index=[True,True,False,False])
```

**Summary:**
My understanding is that pd.join can handle non-indexed and indexed columns, whereas pd.merge cannot. As a result I'm unsure how to achieve this join in pd.join where there is a combination of both indexed and non-indexed columns.

**Example of intersects:**

```
{'different_unique_id': {27: '{582D0636-8DEF-8F22-E053-6C04A8C01BAC}',
  41: '{D9E869FE-7B55-4C36-AC43-695B9033A13B}',
  33: '{93E6821E-554E-40FD-E053-6B04A8C0C1DF}',
  1: '{288DCE29-0589-E510-E050-A8C06205480E}',
  48: '{3A23DDD5-A0E8-41D2-A514-5B09385C301F}',
  52: '{CEB16957-F7FA-4D1B-B45F-A390214735BC}',
  13: '{404A5AF3-9B20-CD2B-E050-A8C063055C7B}',
  16: '{64342BFD-FD07-422C-E053-6C04A8C0FB8A}',
  57: '{29A8E769-8A10-4477-9494-FF55EF5FAE4B}',
  10: '{404A5AF3-0B58-CD2B-E050-A8C063055C7B}',
  21: '{55BDCAE6-0C10-521D-E053-6B04A8C0DD7A}',
  31: '{5C676A02-1781-4152-950C-6E5CA2CBC487}',
  7: '{68FEB20B-142E-38DA-E053-6C04A8C051AE}',
  45: '{8F1B26BD-673F-53DB-E053-6C04A8C03649}',
  12: '{2F115F7A-8F81-4124-9FD4-FB76E742B2C1}',
  36: '{344AB2D7-4B59-4AB4-8F52-75B29BE8C509}',
  20: '{965B6D91-D4B6-95E4-E053-6C04A8C07729}',
  56: '{59872FD9-F39D-4BB9-95F6-91E002D948B1}',
  22: '{6141DFF0-973F-4FEC-A582-7F310B566031}'},
 'unique_id': {27: 10002277489,
  41: 64023255,
  33: 10007367447,
  1: 22229221,
  48: 10033235735,
  52: 100062162615,
  13: 50103744,
  16: 10022903998,
  57: 12015624,
  10: 12154940,
  21: 10024247587,
  31: 100041193990,
  7: 10008230730,
  45: 10091640210,
  12: 202107394,
  36: 5062293,
  20: 48114659,
  56: 10001311242,
  22: 10000443154},
 'street': {27: 'thewharf',
  41: 'parkroad',
  33: 'oldmillclose',
  1: 'thirdavenue',
  48: 'woolnersway',
  52: 'sumnerroad',
  13: 'cliftongardens',
  16: 'windhamroad',
  57: 'westparkroad',
  10: 'grangeroad',
  21: 'staplersroad',
  31: 'strand',
  7: 'amhurstroad',
  45: 'eatonroad',
  12: 'northendroad',
  36: 'belsizegrove',
  20: 'watermillway',
  56: 'orchardplace',
  22: 'thurlowparkroad'},
 'postcode': {27: 'lu72la',
  41: 'cf626nt',
  33: 'hr40aq',
  1: 'bn32pd',
  48: 'sg13ae',
  52: 'gu97jx',
  13: 'ct202ef',
  16: 'bh14rn',
  57: 'ub24af',
  10: 'w55bu',
  21: 'po302dp',
  31: 'tq148aq',
  7: 'e82ag',
  45: 'ch47ew',
  12: 'ha90ae',
  36: 'nw34tt',
  20: 'sw192rw',
  56: 'so143hw',
  22: 'se218hp'},
 'secondary_number': {27: '76',
  41: 'flat6',
  33: '49',
  1: 'flat10',
  48: '145',
  52: '31',
  13: 'flat19',
  16: 'flat7',
  57: '76',
  10: 'flat1',
  21: 'flat1',
  31: 'flat43',
  7: 'flata',
  45: '8',
  12: '42',
  36: 'flat9',
  20: 'flat43',
  56: 'flat156',
  22: 'flat2'},
 'primary_number': {27: 'eastdock',
  41: 'courtlands',
  33: 'watkinscourt',
  1: 'ascothouse',
  48: 'monumentcourt',
  52: 'sumnercourt',
  13: '22-24',
  16: '77',
  57: 'osterleyviews',
  10: '55-59',
  21: '138',
  31: 'leandercourt',
  7: '130',
  45: 'greenbankhall',
  12: 'danescourt',
  36: 'holmefieldcourt',
  20: 'bennetscourtyard',
  56: 'oceanaboulevard',
  22: '124f'},
 'building_name': {27: 'eastdock',
  41: 'courtlands',
  33: 'watkinscourt',
  1: 'ascothouse',
  48: 'monumentcourt',
  52: 'sumnercourt',
  13: None,
  16: None,
  57: 'osterleyviews',
  10: None,
  21: None,
  31: 'leandercourt',
  7: None,
  45: 'greenbankhall',
  12: 'danescourt',
  36: 'holmefieldcourt',
  20: 'bennetscourtyard',
  56: 'oceanaboulevard',
  22: None},
 'building_number': {27: None,
  41: None,
  33: None,
  1: '18-20',
  48: None,
  52: None,
  13: '22-24',
  16: '77',
  57: None,
  10: '55-59',
  21: '138',
  31: None,
  7: '130',
  45: None,
  12: None,
  36: None,
  20: None,
  56: None,
  22: '124f'},
 'sub_building': {27: '76',
  41: 'flat6',
  33: '49',
  1: 'flat10',
  48: '145',
  52: '31',
  13: 'flat19',
  16: 'flat7',
  57: '76',
  10: 'flat1',
  21: 'flat1',
  31: 'flat43',
  7: 'flata',
  45: '8',
  12: '42',
  36: 'flat9',
  20: 'flat43',
  56: 'flat156',
  22: 'flat2'}}
```

Comment: can you add example dataframes, e.g. `df1.sample(n=20).to_dict()` that intersect?

Comment: secondly, you mention dask doesn't handle multi-indexes.  Is there a good reason you can't convert your multi-indices to columns?

Comment: My two indexes are not unique, so my understanding was that dropping "streetname" as a second-tier non-unique index (only using postcode ) would have a significant detriment in performance terms but if I'm wrong that is good news.

Comment: That is probably true.  There are lots of ways to skin a cat though, so it really would be helpful to see what data you are using (including datatypes)

Comment: lastly: what performance do you observe, and what are you hoping to get?

Comment: I'm having difficulty parsing a table in ascii but will try to parse the json - all vars are strings and in terms of performance less than the 1 minute per execution would work. I have simplified the case for this question as my own tables have higher dimensionality but will try to replicate per the question.

Comment: Ok, that sample is now added to the body and all of the dtypes are string.

Comment: It looks like your data needs cleaning.  There is no intersection in the dataframes provided, and there is only one row that doesn't have a null in the joining columns `df[["postcode", "street", "house_name", "house_number"]].dropna()`

Comment: until you fix (or drop) your nulls, there is really no reason to try and join very large nullish dfs

Comment: Let me grab an intersect of an output, one moment (I am dropping nulls pre-join). The challenge is that my programmed output only returns the two IDs presently.

Comment: Ok, that is now done - the challenge is that I have used some intermediaries to facilitate the join (hence higher dimensionality in my dataset compared to the question above, resulting in ~400 combinatorics). An example is concatenating "flat" prior to a variable or concatenating two variables from one dataset. The reason for this is that I haven't solved the original question so presently need to depend on 1:1 joins.

Comment: Well the joined data is not really helpful for trouble shooting.

Comment: Ah, I'm really sorry :-s. I think it might still be useable if only one non-index is used rather than two, as that still gets to the crux of the question (mixing indexed and non-indexed variables in a merge or join)

Comment: Ideas that may be helpful (assuming your multi-GB dfs size can't be reduced e.g. by using `pd.Categorical` or `dropna()`): 
1) concatenate your join indexes/columns and set them as the index, something like: `idx = df.street.str.cat(df.postcode); df.set_index(idx)`.  This should have index performance on all column values you want, and probably open up dask for joins
2) at this scale, SQL comes to mind (with it's own caveats)
3) if you have repeated keys, an inner join can still be extremely expensive, and 1m is a lot of records; 1 minute to join might be asking a lot

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you, at least that brings me down to one index which brings Dask back into play. Bigquery was too expensive due to the volume of combinoratrics and pandasql (postgres) couldn't handle the size (which seems to be a built-in cap) but that was my first thought too. On 3 - yes, it will still have a lot of repeats, only the IDs are sure to be unique but they aren't joinable on anything. Assuming a move to Dask, is a join on both a single index column and a single column (non-index variable) possible together as I had failed to confirm this?

Comment: #this was the closest I was able to get to confirming:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html //////

dd.merge(a, pandas_df)  # fast, //////

dd.merge(a, b, left_index=True, right_index=True)  # fast, //////

dd.merge(a, b, left_index=True, right_on='id')  # half-fast, half-slow //////

dd.merge(a, b, left_on='id', right_on='id')  # slow<br/> //////

But I believe that this is to join a non-indexed variable to an indexed variable, not to join indexed variables with the same name and at the same time join non-indexed variables with the same name.